# Eclipse and Tycho - ${tycho-version}

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

Looking at Tycho tutorials and answers here at Stackoverflow a lot of then contain the variable `${tycho-version}` example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
</plugin>
```

What is nowhere described is who is responsible for resolving this variable. Is it done automatically by Eclipse/M2Eclipse plugin or does this variable means the developer is responsible for specifying the version?

If the developer is responsible where to get the list of versions?

Comment: ${tycho-version} is a variable you have to define it in properties section. or just use the tycho-version directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard idiom for ensuring all Tycho plug-ins are from the same version: if plug-ins from multiple versions clash, it can result in very hard to debug issues. If this is the only place you enter a tycho version, this might seem unnecessary, but if you have to provide configuration for multiple elements, this will be responsible.

In other words, the build configuration should include a value for this property (or it should be set via the -D property syntax, e.g. `mvn clean install -Dtycho-version=1.0.0`).

In order to find out the possible versions, you could execute a [search on maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.tycho%22%20AND%20a%3A%22tycho%22); where you can see the latest version as of today (3rd Apr, 2017) is 1.0.0.

Comment: You should Include this property directly in the POM in the `project/properties/tycho-version` element. You can still override it on the command-line with `-D=tycho-version`, but setting it on the command-line should **not** be the standard use, as it makes you build dependent on external information.